# Периодическое выполнение функции в фоне

Tags: python, асинхронность, threading

пишу Telegram bot. Интерфейс написал, данные добавляются в MySQL БД. Теперь мне нужно реализовать функцию, которая будет запускаться каждые 10 минут и обрабатывать данные в этой БД при этом не мешая работе основного кода.
Я понимаю, что как-то нужно это сделать или через отдельный поток или асинхронную функцию, но прочитал массу документации и не могу понять как это сделать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Из экономии ресурсов на сервере я сделал по другому: написал отдельную от основного когда программу обновляющую бд, программу запускаю раз в сколько мне нужно минут с помощью cron (на любой ОС есть аналоги), она обновляет б.д. и закрывается.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).